# WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name Throws Exception On Azure IIS

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, azure-cloud-services, windows-identity

I have deployed my web application on azure cloud.When i try to get identity user using 
`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`. Name  It throws me following exception

> System.Security.SecurityException:   at
>   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.KerbS4ULogon(String upn,
>   SafeAccessTokenHandle& safeTokenHandle)    at
>   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity..ctor(String
>   sUserPrincipalName, String type)    at
>   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity..ctor(String
>   sUserPrincipalName)

Where as this code works fine on my local environment and domain

Comment: I tried the code on multi app tiers(free/shared/basic), all worked fine. I can get the identity name as following format. IIS APPPOOL\{app name}. Have you changed any configuration of your web app?

Comment: yes , i  added  authenticated user in identity pool. that is custom account in application pool identity

Comment: Are you using Cloud Service instead of Azure Web App?

Comment: I have deployed my web app on azure. I want to access physical directory on azure file system. Before i access azure file system i have to validate pool identity has write permission on azure file directory. When i try to get identity user it throws exception.

Comment: Can you add more details as to what is the version of IIS and what is the application pool identity set to? Is it set to **application pool identity** or something else? Is the pipeline set to **Classic/Integrated**

You also need to provide what authentication is the Site configured to use? Is it using Windows Authentication or anonymous or other?